# Is it possible to "partially" connect to a VPN

Tags: networking, vpn

My university offers a remote access VPN to access paywalled journals, which I often want to use. However they require using the Cisco AnyConnect protocol.

This is a bit annoying because it effectively disconnects and reconnects every connection I have and routes it through the university server.

Is it possible to somehow connect to the VPN in a way where I can define that just the browser will go through the VPN, rather than everything? For example some tunneling trick which will allow me to run a proxy server and connect to it from my browser.

(My Linux is Arch Linux on x86_64, if that matters somehow.)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this.  The Cisco client will try to enforce administrator policy note that working around that may well be a violation of academic conduct.

[Configuring Cisco VPN Anyconnect to use VPN and the local network simultaneously](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55791/configuring-cisco-vpn-anyconnect-to-use-vpn-and-the-local-network-simultaneously).

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux Stack Exchange! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: I don't see how this can be a violation of academic conduct. The whole point of these remote access proxies is to allow the good folks of the academia work from places which are not physically in the university.

Comment: More than likely, your network/security admins have made a decision to not allow [split tunneling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split_tunneling) while connecting to their network.  Trying to get around their security restrictions tends to make network/security admins cranky...

Comment: @Hunter: I see. Well, between making the sysadmin cranky and "violation of academic conduct" there's a few parsecs of distance. :-)

Comment: True, but there's always the possibility that they file a complaint with your dean (or whoever is appropriate) for violating university policy.  At that point the distance can shrink rather quickly...

Comment: It would be a clear violation of at least two employment contracts I've had in the past to have my "work" machines simultaneously connected to more than one network.  In practice this meant that I could not VPN "out" from my desktop at the office, and when connected remotely from a laptop I could not override the policy enforcement that shut down my other interfaces and took over my default route (which is what you're up against).  I don't know if your university has a similar policy.

Answer (score 0):

From your description, maybe the default gateway was replaced by the VPN gateway, or there's a route table entry that has a very small netmask value which causes most traffic been redirected to VPN gateway (for example 0.0.0.0/1 via VPN_GATEWAY).

Look at the output of `ip route`, and see which situation it is. You'll need to delete that "default" traffic redirect entry and add the ip range of your campus network to let them go through the gateway.